# Some help on grep regex

Tags: json, regex, bash, grep, capture

I'm a bit thrown off by the difference between "normal" RegEx and the syntax that grep understands. I'd like to ask for your help on the following.

I have this text in a file "deployments.txt":

```
{"data":[{"id":"local$1cb66e07-2e75-40c4-9ea7-cdda2e62a7e9","name":"some-other-app","servers":["f150ee04-6250-4b97-a2d7-f6511186b6b4"],"applications":["local$1552a8d2-4c9d-4256-b635-a15c4187f4ee"],"lastModified":"Mon, 14 Sep 2015 11:34:52.474 CEST","reconciled":false,"status":"DEPLOYED","href":"https://host123:7777/mmc-3.6.1/api/deployments/local$1cb66e07-2e75-40c4-9ea7-cdda2e62a7e9","clusterIds":[],"clusterNames":[]},{"id":"local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b","name":"interesting-app","servers":["f150ee04-6250-4b97-a2d7-f6511186b6b4"],"applications":["local$87bc69d6-1b92-4e3a-a0f2-724c5d37aeaf"],"lastModified":"Mon, 14 Sep 2015 22:43:15.440 CEST","reconciled":false,"status":"DEPLOYED","href":"https://host123:7777/mmc-3.6.1/api/deployments/local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b","clusterIds":[],"clusterNames":[]}],"total":2}
```

And now I'm interested in this bit:

```
"id":"local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b","name":"interesting-app"
```

Or actually only the clean id that precedes the text `"name":"interesting-app"`

A "normal" regex would be: `.*"id":"(.*?)","name":"interesting-app"` which yields in the capturing group `local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b`

But those capturing groups work differently in grep apparently, figured that out by now and have been banging my head against this since.

So I got this for a grep now:

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":").*?(?=","name":"interesting-app)' deployments.txt
```

But that captures too much, it start with the first `"id":"` it finds and then stops once it finds `","name":"interesting-app`.

So how can I get the result I want here? I want the clean id value that immediately precedes `"name":"interesting-app"`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: No, don't parse `json` with a regex. The general json format is not parseable by a regex, and furthermore for most cases that can be parsed, will be exceptionally error prone.

Comment: I understand and basically agree on your statement, but then how would you advise to digest this in a bash script then? I don't have resources available to build an app with json parsing capabilities unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I've read about jq and similar tools. However, I'm to run this in an enterprise controlled bamboo server. Adding third party libraries for which we don't have to pay big time are distrusted in general, if you get what I mean. I'd rather take the chance of providing a bash script that breaks from time to time that I have to fix because of product changes, compared to the hassle to get these kind of tools available on the server. You know what these dinosaur Linux maintenance teams are like...

Comment: `grep` recognizes Posix Basic Regular Expressions (BREs), which require a lot more backslashes. Normally, you probably want to use Extended Regular Expressions (EREs), which you can do by remembering to always type `egrep` instead of `grep`. Or you can use the `-E` flag. Read [`man 7 regex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) for a detailed description of the two formats, and note that it recommends never using BREs.

Answer (score 1):

[**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a much better tool for parsing JSON in the shell. It has a rather powerful miniature query language for selecting and even modifying JSON data.

Take a gander:

```
$ jq -r '.data | map(select(.name == "interesting-app")) | .[].id' deployments.txt
local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b
```

To explain how this works, first let's look at this simpler query for all `id`s:

```
$ jq -r '.data[].id' deployments.txt
local$1cb66e07-2e75-40c4-9ea7-cdda2e62a7e9
local$6b5fabb5-3e7e-4d16-9664-14977e3b1a7b
```

This selects the `data` key, then `[]` selects all the array elements, then `.id` gets the `id` key from each of the array entries.

My original query adds a `select` filter to the mix to pick out only the entries that have a `name` of `"interesting-app"`. It turns out jq lets you chain together so-called "filters" with UNIX-like pipes.

You can read the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for a full description of everything jq can do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree this would be better, but I have to do with the limited means that I have...

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple regex pattern

```
String patt="(\\.id.*interesting-app\\.)";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is this general enough for you?

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]*(?=","name":"interesting-app")' deployments.txt
```

The problem with **.*?** is that it matches everything between the first **"id":** and the last **"name":"interesting-app"**.